# how to make the s:link open in a new window

Tags: jsf, seam

How to enable opening links exposed via s:link in a new window
http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/seam/09-TagReference/seam-link.html

Comment: Why is this tagged jQuery? Do you prefer jQuery solutions above HTML/taglib solutions?

Comment: simpler solutions as the one you have provided below is preferable. I am a complete novice as for as UI is concerned and just added jQuery to see if there was an easier alternative there.

The solution given below is what I was looking for.

Comment: I'd suggest to pause with JSF and learn HTML first :) That's after all also what JSF generates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `target="_blank"` as in [normal links](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp).

```
<s:link target="_blank">
```